# VBSCRIPT check same value in many row but in different place

Tags: vbscript

I need help for this problem, I have multiple rows in a text file (.txt) as the example

1. 0001 0002 0005 0007
2. 0004 0005 0009 0004
3. 0004 0009 0006 0004
4. xxxx 0006 zzzz kkkk
5. xxxx zzzz ..........

I must check if the third element of each row (0005 in fist row) is the same of second element of next row (0005 in second row), I must continue to check for each row (0009 in second row with 0009 in third row)

How can i check if the value are equal ? maybe put in array ?

thanks for answer

Comment: well is possible have the same number in a row (First row 0005 0005 0005 0005 second row 0005 0005 0005 0005) how can check if the third element of first row is the same in the second element of second row ?

Comment: read - split - extract - check

Answer (score 0):

Keeping an array is overkill. Just keep two variables, one which has the elements of one line in an array and one with has the elements of the next. Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso,f,problem, i, lineone, linetwo

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Item(0),1,true)

lineone = Split(Trim(f.ReadLine))
i = 1
problem = false

Do While f.AtEndOfStream <> True
  linetwo = Split(Trim(f.ReadLine))
  i = i+1
  If lineone(2) <> linetwo(1) Then
     MsgBox "Problem at line " & i
     problem = True
     Exit Do
  End If
  lineone = linetwo 'for next pass through the loop
Loop
f.close
If Not problem Then MsgBox "File is Okay"
```

When I feed the script the following file:

```
0001 0002 0005 0007
0004 0005 0009 0004
0004 0009 0006 0004
0004 0006 0006 0004
0004 0006 0006 0008
```

The script prints "File is Okay"

But when I feed it this file:

```
0001 0002 0005 0007
0004 0005 0009 0004
0004 0006 0006 0004
0004 0006 0006 0004
0004 0006 0006 0008
```

The script prints "Problem at line 3"

I didn't do any error checking to handle the case where there are fewer than two lines in the file or some of the lines lack the expected number of entries. Obviously, you should make this more robust.